# MySql second-smallest element in each group

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table similar to the following:

```
    date    |   expiry
-------------------------    
2010-01-01  | 2010-02-01
2010-01-01  | 2010-03-02
2010-01-01  | 2010-04-04
2010-02-01  | 2010-03-01
2010-02-01  | 2010-04-02
```

In the table, each date may have multiple 'expiry' values. I need a query that returns the n-th smallest expiry in each date. For example, for n = 2, I would expect:

```
     date    |   expiry
-------------------------       
2010-01-01  | 2010-03-02
2010-02-01  | 2010-04-02
```

My trouble is that AFAIK, there is no aggregate function which returns the n'th largest/smallest element, so I can't use 'GROUP BY'. More specifically, if I had a magical MIN() aggregate that accepts a second parameter 'offset', I would write:

```
SELECT MIN(expiry, 1) FROM table WHERE date IN ('2010-01-01', '2010-02-01') GROUP BY date
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Absolutely has to be done inside a single query? It's particularly difficult because MySQL doesn't support `LIMIT` clauses inside subqueries. It may end up being simplest to just select everything and work out which record you actually want outside of the database.

Comment: @Chad Birch. If I have not choice - I'll do as you suggested, but I feel the requirement is simple and useful enough for me to be able to do it with a single MySql query. I might be wrong, tough :-)

Comment: Tagged with 'greatest-n-per-group'. Some of the answers have a general way of dealing with this missing feature in MySQL using clever tricks; the ones that generate a full group set should be selectable against. Good luck finding the magical code.

Comment: @Chad - care to post your comment as an answer? After reading some of the posts tagged 'greatest-n-per-group' as suggested by [pst](http://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst), I think you are right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One hack is to use group_concat. Group by the date and concat the expiry date in ascending order and use substring_index function to fetch the nth value.

```
mysql> select * from expiry;
+------------+------------+
| date       | expiry     |
+------------+------------+
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01 |
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-03-02 |
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-04-04 |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-03-01 |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-04-02 |
+------------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT mdate,
       Substring_index(Substring_index(edate, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS exp_date
FROM   (SELECT `date`               AS mdate,
               GROUP_CONCAT(expiry order by expiry asc separator ",") AS edate
        FROM   expiry
        GROUP  BY mdate) e1;  
+------------+------------+
| mdate      | exp_date   |
+------------+------------+
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-03-02 |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-04-02 |
+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In the example here the sub-query gives the following output:

```
+------------+----------------------------------+
| mdate      | edate                            |
+------------+----------------------------------+
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01,2010-03-02,2010-04-04 |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-03-01,2010-04-02            |
+------------+----------------------------------+
```

substring_index(edate,',',2) goes 2 elements forward (for nth element substitute 2 by n).

```
+------------+------------------------------+
| mdate      | substring_index(edate,',',2) |
+------------+------------------------------+
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-02-01,2010-03-02        |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-03-01,2010-04-02        |
+------------+------------------------------+
```

we run another substring_index on the above output to get only the 2nd element (the last element of the intermediate result) using substring_index(substring_index(edate,',',2),',',-1)

```
+------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| mdate      | substring_index(substring_index(edate,',',2),',',-1) |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| 2010-01-01 | 2010-03-02                                           |
| 2010-02-01 | 2010-04-02                                           |
+------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

If there are too many values to concat you might run out of group_concat_max_len value (default 1024, but can be set higher).

UPDATE: The SQL given above will give nth element even when there is less n elements for tht group. To avoid that the sql can be modified as:

```
SELECT mdate,
       IF(cnt >= 2,Substring_index(Substring_index(edate, ',', 2), ',', -1),NULL) AS exp_date
FROM   (SELECT `date`               AS mdate,
               count(expiry) as cnt,
               GROUP_CONCAT(expiry order by expiry asc separator ",") AS edate
        FROM   expiry
        GROUP  BY mdate) e1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you take your n value and use it to control your return size.
For example, say you wanted the third lowest value...
What you're actually after is the largest value from the bottom 3 values

So it would be TOP 1 FROM (TOP n ORDER BY col ASC)

EDIT: as noted in comments by @Chad Birch, this approach may be problematic if you are not able to use LIMIT inside of subqueries.

EDIT2:
Here is an interesting workaround using `JOIN`s with `LIMIT`
http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/211239

Comment: MySQL's equivalent of MSSQL's `TOP` is a `LIMIT` clause, but it doesn't support this in subqueries, so this isn't an option if it needs to be done in one query.

Comment: EDIT2 is a broken link.